# Append each div to own parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I dynamically create the DOM structure using jQuery by pulling data from the backend (which I do not touch). Currently the backend is outputting 4 text elements on the page. I have an each loop that based on how many elements on the page to create matching box divs. Moral of the story, I need each element to be placed in their own seperate div. Currently the first div contains all 4 items, the second contains 3, third contains 2 and forth contains 1. An example how it looks visually:

```
---------------------
|Item1              |
|Item2              |
|Item3              |
|Item4              |
---------------------
---------------------
|Item1              |
|Item2              |
|Item3              |
|                   |
---------------------
---------------------
|Item1              |
|Item2              |
|                   |
|                   |
---------------------
---------------------
|Item1              |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
---------------------
```

below is the jquery:

```
  $('.sequencing').append('<div class="sequence_boxes sortable sortable_area"></div>');

  $('.sequence_option').each(function(i) {
    $('<div class="box"></div>').appendTo($('.sequence_boxes'));
    $(this).appendTo($('.box')); 
  });
```

Comment: What did you use to draw the elements? They look nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe problem is that you're appending `this` to `$('.box')`, which will match *all* boxes and so you'll get cloned elements.

Instead, just append to the one you just created:

```
$('.sequencing').append('<div class="sequence_boxes sortable sortable_area"></div>');
$('.sequence_option').each(function(i) {
    $('<div class="box"></div>').appendTo($('.sequence_boxes')).append(this);
    // We're doing the append here ----------------------------^
});
```

Or a bit clearer without chaining:

```
$('.sequencing').append('<div class="sequence_boxes sortable sortable_area"></div>');
$('.sequence_option').each(function(i) {
    var box = $('<div class="box"></div>');
    box.appendTo($('.sequence_boxes'));
    box.append(this);
});
```

You might also want to only look up `.sequence_boxes` *once*, rather than repeating the lookup, and maybe to optimize the browser's work you could only attach the `.sequence_boxes` when you're done filling it in:

```
var boxes = $('<div class="sequence_boxes sortable sortable_area"></div>');
$('.sequence_option').each(function(i) {
    $('<div class="box"></div>').appendTo(boxes).append(this);
});
boxes.appendTo($('.sequencing'));
```